# The possibility to choose between two pages when clicking on a button WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, button

I have this code,

```
<div class="EMP-Buton-Cere-Oferta-PF">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url($header_button_url); ?>" class="header-btn sr-btn sr-lg-btn"><?php echo esc_html($getfree_quote_button); ?></a>
</div>
```

and I want to make it possible for a small popup to appear when clicked and for the user to choose between two pages.

Does anybody know how can I make this?

Thank you!

Comment: You would need some Javascript to make the popup appear

Comment: Should I do like this?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Comment: If that's what you want, give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have to do the following three steps

1- Create the desired button or element that when you click it, a modal with links inside will be displayed

2- In the next step, you have to write the CSS codes that are necessary to show and hide the modal, of course, you can change some parts according to your site's style.

3- Finally, you need to set events for the button and div with main-overlay ID to make each modal show/hide when clicked.

```js
// Variables
const mainButton = document.querySelector('#main-button');
const mainModal = document.querySelector('#main-modal');
const mainOverlay = document.querySelector('#main-overlay');

// Events
if( mainButton ) mainButton.addEventListener('click', openModal);
if( mainOverlay ) mainOverlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// Functions
function openModal(e) {
  mainOverlay.classList.add('active');
  mainModal.classList.add('active');
}

function closeModal(e) {
  mainOverlay.classList.remove('active');
  mainModal.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
/* Button */
.button {
  padding:8px 24px;
  border-radius:8px;
  background-color:#0ea5e9;
  font-size:16px;
  border:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* Modal */
.modal {
  width:360px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:12px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  margin:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:32px;
  z-index:999;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.3s linear;
}

.modal.active {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition:all 0.3s linear .2s;
}

.modal ul {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  list-style:none;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap:16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal ul li {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.modal ul li a {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#F7F7F7;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  border-radius:8px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#333333;
  font-size:18px;
}

.modal ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#E7E7E7;
}

/* Overlay */
.overlay {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position:fixed;
  inset:0;
  margin:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:32px;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 0.3s linear;
}

.overlay.active {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<!-- Your Button -->
<button class="button" id="main-button">Click Me</button>

<!-- Your Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="main-modal">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#link-1">Link-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link-2">Link-2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="main-overlay"></div>
```